# Bootstrap table force all table headers to display on single line

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

My table headers look like this:

[image: table headers]

I don't like  how some of the headers are rendered on multiple lines.  I want all of them to be on a single line, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also, I don't like that the Notes header is taking up so much table width.  How can I reduce the width that it takes up?

I am using `table-responsive` [as the w3schools example shows here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_table-responsive&stacked=h).

**Update:** Note that just giving the longer header columns more column grid space: (ex: `col-sm-4` as opposed to say `col-sm-1` or `col-sm-2`) is not a good solution because that would take up way too many grid spots.  Afterwords I would not have enough grid spots left for the rest of my columns.

Basically I always want the column headers to be on a single line.  If the column header can't fit on a single line, then go into responsive mode to ensure that the column headers will be on single lines.

Here is a code snippet.  Make sure to click "Full Page":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Table</h2>
    <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname really really long last name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
              parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
              eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum
              nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</td>
            <td>Pitt</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
              parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
              eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum
              nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</td>
            <td>USA</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code you've pasted doesn't match the image. There is no notes fields in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `col-[viewport]-[size]`. Remember the column sizes should total to 12. Refer changes below:

I have randomly set the column sizes, you can modify as per your requirements: As below, the total should never be greater than 12 `1+3+4+1+2+1 = 12`

```
<tr>
    <th class="col-xs-1">#</th>
    <th class="col-xs-3">Firstname</th>
    <th class="col-xs-4">Lastname really really long last name</th>
    <th class="col-xs-1">Age</th>
    <th class="col-xs-2">City</th>
    <th class="col-xs-1">Country</th>
</tr>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Table</h2>
    <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-xs-1">#</th>
            <th class="col-xs-3">Firstname</th>
            <th class="col-xs-4">Lastname really really long last name</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Age</th>
            <th class="col-xs-2">City</th>
            <th class="col-xs-1">Country</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
              parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
              eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum
              nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</td>
            <td>Pitt</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
              parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at
              eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Aenean lacinia bibendum
              nulla sed consectetur. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
              dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</td>
            <td>USA</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

If you content is large and doesn't fit in a single line, it just wont; even if you make it responsive. Responsive tries to fit all in one line by adding double lines if needed.

> Ways to achieve what you need :
>
> > 1. Adjust column sizes and makes other columns smaller
> > 2. Lower the font size to fit it in one line.
> > 3. Write custom class specifying the width

For example,default width is :

```
.col-xs-4{
width:33.33%;
}
```

If you want custom width, create classes like below[IMP : Total should be exactly `100%`]

```
.col-custom-1{
width:20%
}
.col-custom-2{
width:20%
}
.col-custom-3{
width:20%
}
.col-custom-4{
width:20%
}
.col-custom-5{
width:20%
}
```

You can adjust width as per requirement or use inline width directly, I prefer classes.

Comment: I used to add the Zurb plugin for responsive tables that does the same thing, but I think this approach is better if you don't want to integrate 819374013 different plugins/frameworks.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It almost works.  The problem is that the column: "Lastname really really long last name" is still taking up two lines.  I know that one response would be to just give that column more column grid spaces, but that would take up too much column grid spaces for the rest of my columns.  I thought that this was the whole point of the `table-responsive` class: that it will go into responsive mode and each column would continue to take up only one line. Any ideas?

Comment: The `.table-responsive` class just adds a horizontal scroll on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference.  [Read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_tables.asp)

Comment: @Neil Updated my answer to add the options available for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Django templates might help solve [the multiple lines issue](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/)

you can separate your html instead of multiplicity

My example,
let us say we have two files that are filled with header multiple lines.

This is the base.html

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
<!-- DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block head_title %}Learn You English{% endblock head_title %}</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- base css  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" />
<style>
{% block style %}{% endblock style %}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

{% include "messages_display.html" %}
<div class'container'>
{% block content %}
<!-- end of block html -->
{% endblock content %}
</div>

<!-- <img src='{% static "img/beach.jpg" %}' />
 -->


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how you could get rid of the multiple lines

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
 {% endblock content %}
```

.
Post_list.html is the example

```
<!--obj == query set-->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <!-- Search get method--> 
<form method='GET' action ''>
<input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search posts' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
<input type='submit' vlaue='Search' />
</form>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        {% if obj.image %}
        <img src='{{ obj.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
        {% endif %}
        <div class="caption">
        {% if obj.draft %}<h3>Staff only: Draft</h3>{% endif %} {% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff ONLY: Future Post</h3>{% endif %}
        <h3><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a> <small>{{ obj.publish}} </small></h3>
        {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}<p>{% endif %}
        <p>{{ obj.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
        <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<hr/>
</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- Pagination modified q for 
&q={{ request.GET.q }}" is keeping the search chararcter while switching 
the page in pagination
-->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ object_list.number }} of {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>


</div>
<!-- end of block html -->
{% endblock content %}
```

I am not sure about the width but maybe looking into the following could help

```
<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
```